# How to force radio buttons to remain checked when checking another radio buttons field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I have two ratings fields on my page, when the first rating is checked and I check the second one, the first one is unchecked. It's not a problem in back-end because the value of the ratings is already saved but for the visitors it's a problem because the stars disappears.

Is there a way in javascript or jQuery to say : if this field is check it remains check ?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<fieldset class="rate">
    <input id="5-stars-1" type="radio" name="firstRate" value="5" />
    <label for="5-stars-1">5</label>
    <input id="4-stars-1" type="radio" name="firstRate" value="4" />
    <label for="4-stars-1">5</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="rate2">
    <input id="5-stars-2" type="radio" name="secondRate" value="5" />
    <label for="5-stars-2">5</label>
    <input id="4-stars-2" type="radio" name="secondRate" value="4" />
    <label for="4-stars-2">5</label>
</fieldset>
```

Do you have any idea ?

If you need more infos or more extract from my code don't mind to ask !

Comment: You're using radio buttons, this is how they are designed to work. If you don't want this behaviour, ie. both values can be checked at once, use checkboxes

Comment: Ah yes you're right it's radio button and not checkboxes.. My bad. With radio buttons there are no solutions to this ?

Comment: @Nicolas You are asking about the checkbox. but in your code i can see the radio buttons. Actually both radio button and checkbox having different behavior.

Comment: No, @NicolasTwil. There's no solution to this with radio buttons because that's how radio buttons are meant to work. You should use them when you want only one option out of many to be selected. In other cases use checkboxes

Comment: `With radio buttons there are no solutions to this?` There may well be, by using some rather hacky JS logic, but it's pointless to do that when you can simply change their type to `checkbox` and be done, no other code required.

Comment: I thought that switching from radio to checkbox would change my design but it didn't, the solution is way easier than I thought, thank you guys it looked easy for you but it really helped me thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Alright so thanks to Rory and Sathish, the answer is really simple :

Radio are designed to be checked once at a time so I couldn't do what I wanted, instead I simply need to switch to checkboxes and the problem is solved !

Thanks again !